# How do I make gcc's linker respect the value of --sysroot?

Tags: gcc, build, linker, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile a simple test program for aarch64, from my x86 host.  I've made myself a sysroot by grabbing an aarch64 Ubuntu docker image, installing `libssl-dev` inside of it, and then extracting the rootfs to `/sysroot`.  I installed the `gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu` package on the host, to get a cross compiler.  I have a simple test program, in `test.c`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>


void main(void) {
        printf("init...");
        SSL_library_init();
        printf("init done!");
}
```

I've tried to compile it using the `--sysroot` option to specify where to find the headers and dynamic libraries, like so, but it doesn't work.

```
root@6ef3093c482b:/build# aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc test.c --sysroot=/sysroot -lssl -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 10.2.1-6' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-10/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-10 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --without-target-system-zlib --enable-multiarch --enable-fix-cortex-a53-843419 --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=aarch64-linux-gnu --program-prefix=aarch64-linux-gnu- --includedir=/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-mutex
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/cc1 -quiet -v -imultiarch aarch64-linux-gnu -isysroot /sysroot test.c -quiet -dumpbase test.c -mlittle-endian -mabi=lp64 -auxbase test -version -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -o /tmp/ccf8LnPB.s
GNU C17 (Debian 10.2.1-6) version 10.2.1 20210110 (aarch64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 10.2.1 20210110, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.0, isl version isl-0.23-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/sysroot/usr/local/include/aarch64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/include-fixed"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/include
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/include
 /sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu
 /sysroot/usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C17 (Debian 10.2.1-6) version 10.2.1 20210110 (aarch64-linux-gnu)
    compiled by GNU C version 10.2.1 20210110, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.0, isl version isl-0.23-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 5a0b79cdec93300bb2aa430deb2c2964
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/as -v -EL -mabi=lp64 -o /tmp/cctZEbBz.o /tmp/ccf8LnPB.s
GNU assembler version 2.35.2 (aarch64-linux-gnu) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.35.2
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/:/sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/sysroot/lib/../lib/:/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/:/sysroot/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/:/sysroot/lib/:/sysroot/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mlittle-endian' '-mabi=lp64'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccOhCglA.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s --sysroot=/sysroot --build-id --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 -X -EL -maarch64linux --fix-cortex-a53-843419 -pie /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10 -L/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib -L/sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L/sysroot/lib/../lib -L/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -L/sysroot/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib -L/sysroot/lib -L/sysroot/usr/lib /tmp/cctZEbBz.o -lssl -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state -lc -lgcc --push-state --as-needed -lgcc_s --pop-state /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/../lib/crtn.o
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `pthread_once@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `dlclose@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `dlsym@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_init@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `fstat@GLIBC_2.33'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_wrlock@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `dladdr@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `stat@GLIBC_2.33'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `dlerror@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `dlopen@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock@GLIBC_2.34'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /sysroot/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.3: undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy@GLIBC_2.34'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems like gcc *is* adding `/sysroot` to the LIBRARY_PATH, but it's putting at the end so it's being ignored in favor of the slightly outdated version shipped with the toolchain.  How can I tell `gcc` to prefer the libraries I'm pointing it at, rather than the ones it shipped with?

Comment: Ended up (kind of) solving it for myself, in my particular use-case.  I didn't realize that Debian supported installing packages for e.g. arm64 directly into the `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu` directory; I ended up getting rid of my sysroot at `/sysroot`, and using `dpkg --add-architecture arm64 && apt install libssl-dev:arm64` instead.  Then, `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc test.c -lssl` works just fine on its own, no custom include or linker directories required!

Comment: You might want to add `-lcrypto -lz -pthread` to your linkage command.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem, with the same root cause, which is that my programs have been getting linked with the wrong version of `libc`; the one from my build host rather than from my sysroot. It turns out that your comment pointed me toward a solution, sort of: I just deleted everything in `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/` (in your case, `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib/`).  I also deleted `/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/` for good measure. It's more a work-around than a real solution, though.